# Viewing the docker container name in syslog

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with many services.  Whenever I run `docker-compose up`, I see the names of the services and it's awesome.

The problem is the names of the services are not visible in syslog. Any tips?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
mydocker:
  image: mydocker
  command: echo mydocker
  log_driver: syslog
  log_opt:
    syslog-address: "<url-goes-here>"

yourdocker:
  image: mydocker
  command: echo your
  log_driver: syslog
  log_opt:
    syslog-address: "<url-goes-here>"
```

**running the command**

```
myawesomeserver/temp$ docker-compose up
Creating temp_mydocker_1
Creating temp_yourdocker_1
Attaching to temp_mydocker_1, temp_yourdocker_1
mydocker_1   | my
yourdocker_1 | your
temp_mydocker_1 exited with code 0
temp_yourdocker_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```